# SOLVED: Configuring Tyan IPMI to use the shared LAN interface

Tags: linux, ipmi, ipmitool

I am using Debian 10.9 over a Tyan Thunder SX TN70EB7106 server. To use IPMI I installed the tools:

```
apt install freeipmi-tools ipmitool
```

Configured the network

```
# ipmitool lan set 1 ipsrc static
# ipmitool lan set 1 ipaddr 172.16.2.103
# ipmitool lan set 1 netmask 255.255.0.0
# ipmitool lan set 1 defgw ipaddr 172.16.0.254
```

and apparently, these changes were accepted

```
# ipmitool lan print 1
Set in Progress         : Set Complete
...
IP Address Source       : Static Address
IP Address              : 172.16.2.103
Subnet Mask             : 255.255.0.0
...
SNMP Community String   : AMI
IP Header               : TTL=0x40 Flags=0x40 Precedence=0x00 TOS=0x10
BMC ARP Control         : ARP Responses Enabled, Gratuitous ARP Disabled
Gratituous ARP Intrvl   : 0.0 seconds
Default Gateway IP      : 172.16.0.254
```

But after reboot, the IP is not responding.

```
# ping 172.16.2.103
PING 172.16.2.103 (172.16.2.103) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 172.16.2.3 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.16.2.3 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Did I miss a step?  What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution to this question. Tyan servers don't share an ethernet interface. To use IPMI you have to use the specific IPMI ethernet port.